# AWS EBS Snapshots created by user vs ones created by AWS Backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Let's assume I have an EC2 instance with 2 EBS volumes. One is, of course, root volume for the instance (ebs-root) and the other is for specific app data (ebs-appdata). There is an active AWS Backup plan that includes ebs-appdata volume and gets everything backed up on regular basis.

Now for specific reasons I would like to manually create new EBS Snapshot for ebs-appdata volume but in such way that it is a full snapshot. Is Snapshot just Snapshot for AWS and no matter how it is created it will always be incremental?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "specific reasons"?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a 1G EBS volume and take its snapshot. The snapshot will then comprise this data on S3:

1. 2K files (= 1G / 512K), each file holding the data for one EBS block. EBS blocks are 512K long. The data in each file will be the same that you would get on your machine by calling `dd /dev/$volume bs=512k count=1 skip=$index` over your volume device, modulo encryption.
2. An index file with the mappings between block index (offset into the logical volume in 512k increments) and the S3 file with the block data. It may also reference the parent snapshot, if any.

When you (or AWS) create a child snapshot, it only creates new files for the changed blocks on S3, and puts the references to the new files to the index.

If you are so inclined, you can create a EBS snapshot of data on your local hard drive, and you will be able to restore it to an EBS volume. AWS provides [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) to do that. It does not give you direct access to the underlying files through S3 API, but does something very close to that. You can add blocks to the snapshot, and you can list the blocks added so far.

> Is Snapshot just Snapshot for AWS and no matter how it is created it will always be incremental?

When AWS creates the snapshots from EBS volumes (through [EC2.CreateSnapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSnapshot.html)), it does it incrementally.

However, this is just an implementation detail you should not be too concerned about. Even if you delete a snapshot using the API, the blocks that are being referenced by the indexes of any child snapshots are not deleted.

I'm not sure what exactly is going under the hood when you do that. Maybe the indexes get merged; maybe the old index is retained on the disk and just marked as invisible; maybe the new index file is not getting explicitly created in the first place and is always reconstructed from the chain of changes. But the (effective) list of the blocks and their references, and the data files of the blocks used are preserved on S3 as long as there's something referencing them.

Only when you delete an old snapshot, and only when some of its blocks have since been overwritten and not used any more by any newer snapshots, do these blocks get garbage collected.

If you create a snapshot from a EBS volume and call [EBS.ListSnapshotBlocks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/APIReference/API_ListSnapshotBlocks.html) on it, you will get the complete list of the blocks referenced by this snapshot, even if some of them were initially created by an earlier snapshot.